# Bigger carry on baggage in Emirates

Tags: luggage, emirates

Emirates has a [baggage policy](https://www.cheapoair.ca/travel/baggage-fees/?btype=international&airlinecode=EK*FZ) as follows,

[image]

Apparently, I have a carry on baggage of size (25+33+64)=122cm.

What should I do now?

Comment: What's your problem? Your luggage is within the given limits for checked luggage...

Comment: Check it in would be the obvious solution. Do you have any other hold luggage?

Comment: @Relaxed, I have two more to check in.

Comment: @Relaxed, and a guitar.

Comment: So you have a total of four bags to check, a carry on that is too large and a guitar? I suggest you contact Emirates directly: https://www.emirates.com/english/help/contact-emirates/

Answer (score 1):

Emirates is very strict about carry-on allowance and they check quite often but not always. So would not risk it without a backup plan. Weight is strictly enforced too, by the way.

Your bag exceeds two dimensions by 5cm which is not much but if they make you try it in the sizer, it will not fit if it is rigid. A soft bag though, if not completely full, will fit, so check if you can squeeze it to the required size, even the official measures are larger. If it does, chances are that you will be good to go.

Now, if it does not fit, getting a new bag within the limit is not that difficult. The size Emirates allows for carry-on is fairly common among airlines (8" x 15" x 22"), although many use 14" instead of 15". Look for a bag within that size. Now I had a lot to carry and Emirates is one of the [few airlines that does not accept a *personal item*](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84089/which-airlines-do-not-allow-a-personal-item-in-addition-to-a-carry-on) in addition to a carry-on, so I asked [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/do-carry-on-size-duffel-bags-exist) earlier this year. Answers do have some good options but I could not get one in-time from Ecuador, so I had a custom-bag made to the exact maximum allowed by Emirates.